# Finding table in SQL Server db with name similar with some string?

Tags: java, sql

I need to find table in my DB with similar name to some string. For example, I need to select table called `Some_Table` and I have string `SomeTable` as table name. I can not split string and add `_` because some tables really have names as `SomeTable`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sobjects.name FROM sysobjects sobjects where sobjects.xtype = 'U' and sobjects.name like '%YOUR_STRING_HERE%';
```

Although `like` is a substring search. If you really need fuzzy search (maybe I used wrong term, I mean the search of "close" strings), probably you're screwed up - there is no way to do it with standard tools.

Consider searching table name using substring. For your example, you may want to use `%some%` as pattern.

Comment: This is not what I need. I just tied. Maybe if I split string and search for all parts in table name, e.g. TABLE_NAME like '%Some%' and TABLE_NAME like '%Table%'? I ll try. Thanks.

Comment: @Aleksandar Yes, that's an option too.